# String interpolation with template

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, string-formatting, string-interpolation

I want to use string interpolation with a template, but I can't get it working. I have the following code:

```
public string Parse(string template, params dynamic[] objects)
{
    return $"text text {objects[0].PropertyOne} {objects[0].PropertyThree} text text";
}
```

This works fine, but I want to use the string template passed into the method, so it seems I need something like this:

```
public string Parse(string template, params dynamic[] objects)
{
    return string.Format(template, objects[0].PropertyOne, objects[0].PropertyThree);
}
```

But I don't know how many parameters will be passed, or with which properties (hence the dynamic type). I need something that would work like this:

```
public string Parse(string template, params dynamic[] objects)
{
    // template = "text text {objects[0].PropertyOne} {objects[0].PropertyThree} text text"
    return string.Format(template, objects);
}
```

Everywhere I look it says string interpolation is just an abstraction of string.Format, or that it uses string.Format in the end, so it sounds like something like this should be possible. Can I do what I aim for without reflection?

Comment: String.Format needs numerical placeholders (`{0}` and such), you cannot specify variables or expressions

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to write a method that takes a formatting template and N params; that's what string.Format does. For your code to then be a one liner that returns string.Format of the input arguments makes it especially pointless - Instead of calling your Parse() (which appears to be a wildly incorrect name, btw; this is the *opposite* of parsing) method, the calling site should just call string.Format itself, or use an interpolated string on the variables it has locally

Comment: If your method has some value to add, then you should look at FormattableString, but be sure you actually have a use case for it. For example Entity Framework makes good use of formattable strings when it does a raw SQL execution; it is important for sql injection prevention to get access to the placeholdered string before it is formatted so that it can be made into a parameterized statement

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it dynamic as you have mentioned in your question.

You can do like this

```
// template = "text text {0} {1} text text"

String.Format(template, objects[0].PropertyOne, objects[0].PropertyThree);
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___) is the official documentation.

Comment: And this is a problem for me, since I don't know how many placeholders the template will have, or which properties should be used.

Comment: That’s why I said you can’t do that, you need to write code for that to define how do you want to get the property of object.

Comment: @rock_crusheria you issue resolved?